# How do I create a dynamic array of const pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, constants

I create a dynamic array of pointers like so:

```
int ** A;
A = new int*[10];
```

How do I create a dynamic array of const pointers? Where does the const go?

Comment: You don't do that in C...you might in C++.  Which language are you really using?  Also, you might want to consider how you'd initialize those constant pointers to something useful.  Once they're allocated, you can't change them, so ...?

Comment: C++. Ok, so I want an array of pointers where I can't modify the objects they're pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Courtesy of [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/):

```
A = new int * const bar[10];
```

That will give you an array 10 long of pointers that can't be set to anything. You should also declare A as:

```
int * const *A;
```

Otherwise you'll have `const` casting problems.

Or perhaps you want an array of 10 pointers to constant `int`:

```
a = new const int *a[10];
```

Comment: The problem is `const` objects must be initialized at declaration.

Comment: @JesseGood - Yep. Don't know what OP is really after.

Comment: Gah my head is about to explode. I'm just after an array of pointers where I can't modify the objects they are pointing to.

Comment: @Frank - Then it's "array of pointer to const T", not "array of const pointer to T" :) If your head is about to explode, you're in good company. There's a reason a tool like cdecl was invented--everyone needs it!